# Parsing json "dict of dicts" into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I love this new card game called Keyforge and I am an amateur data scientist that wants to provide the community with some cool tools and features. My ultimate aim is to develop an app that scans a fresh new deck's QR code and it tells you on the spot how good your new deck is and how it places compared to the rest of decks in the world. All of this using machine learning.

The company that makes the game has an API where I am pulling all the data from and it comes as a JSON object. I believe that it is a dict of dicts (I copied some of the JSON file below for you to confirm I am right). I don't have too much experience with JSON objects, but I am comfortable with python in general.

I am trying to parse or extract the data (all of it or some of it) into an sqlite3 database. I am fairly new to databases, so I am struggling.

Apart from doing JSON to sqlite 3, I also need to manipulate the data into the format I need for my learning algorithm, but I think I can cope with that.

I have tried many things that I found here and online, but none of them are working.

Below is the beginning and some middle part of one of the JSON files, so you can understand how the data is structured. I have read that I need to flatten it out first and I have tried a few things, but I have had no luck so far.
My aim is to have a table where each row is a deck (or sample for the learning algorithm). Below you can see a couple of decks: "Dr. The Old Jeffries" and "Gendry V. Rineity, the Enigmatic". The columns of the table would be a unique id number (the main key, auto-increase, etc.), basically 1, 2, 3, ... and so on, and the rest of the columns would be "name", "expansion", "power_level", etc. The actual minimum data I really need is the id number (the main key, auto-increase), the "card_number" for each of the 36 cards in each deck (this is a number from 1 to 370, which are the cards in the game) and then columns for "wins", "losses", "casual_wins" and "casual_losses", which is vital to train the learning algorithm on what is a good successful deck.

```
{
  "count": 459959, #this is how many decks are live in the World
  "data": [        #this contains the name of each deck and other data
    {
      "name": "Dr. \"The Old\" Jeffries",
      "expansion": 341,
      "power_level": 0,
      "chains": 0,
      "wins": 0,
      "losses": 0,
      "id": "ec86db52-e41e-4e6a-9f1a-a2d0e3d3277d",
      "is_my_deck": false,
      "notes": [],
      "is_my_favorite": false,
      "is_on_my_watchlist": false,
      "casual_wins": 0,
      "casual_losses": 0,
      "_links": {
        "houses": [
          "Brobnar",
          "Dis",
          "Logos"
        ],
        "cards": [        #this is the list of 36 cards for this deck
          "d438faa9-7920-437a-8d1c-682fade5d350",
          "d438faa9-7920-437a-8d1c-682fade5d350",
          "0ef760a3-68b9-42a9-93fa-419ea171917b",
          "68e2188c-4002-43d4-9fe1-0262df26c33f",
          "68e2188c-4002-43d4-9fe1-0262df26c33f",
          "3d650fe4-817a-4922-ba0f-297c1ebf816d",
          "652c4e38-c4fa-4e30-8f8d-036e95249529",
          "d4f666db-302f-43d0-b0af-bd03071f92ce",
          "0c3231e1-1230-4e7d-890e-6d3149125de2",
          "d792387f-8392-49b3-ad7c-ccaf7552256f",
          "f2c71c05-7a23-4465-8a89-82ab8e258a68",
          "e1312fbf-c297-4d9f-b403-2d892271de62",
          "d2edea65-7c2f-487f-a6f4-f44a077c4a65",
          "10715fd2-031a-47ca-9119-9b7b2ec1d2c0",
          "10715fd2-031a-47ca-9119-9b7b2ec1d2c0",
          "be492d70-5c87-441e-8223-79fb2bce85c9",
          "d42dd1d0-3462-410f-b683-dd0768b84188",
          "5607fecd-b90e-4e12-84bc-cb36d079117c",
          "ea2a390e-e121-4cbd-96c5-2430cc600e81",
          "96548d93-b318-40e3-9f5c-3297c8070ebd",
          "17e9dbd4-53cb-4c75-bdad-48e1550ff1e7",
          "916f271b-9928-437c-bfc4-d60d32af8c7c",
          "9ed7d241-1ca3-4a2a-b067-bb44776f7d4b",
          "b8343462-b5d7-48b0-9e3b-f020c5e73c55",
          "1283215c-3ea2-4d2b-9af4-452d7c0d57d9",
          "1283215c-3ea2-4d2b-9af4-452d7c0d57d9",
          "448c1335-d45b-473e-b222-d71f31ba0292",
          "448c1335-d45b-473e-b222-d71f31ba0292",
          "45d564a2-fcc9-4baa-8dc8-8e1a0fe2a37a",
          "5a521238-f524-48e3-b121-40c16e1f7610",
          "57bccc52-b6a1-4d11-b9d9-6356d8ac279c",
          "cd83ebe7-f961-4e5e-a00e-046d1be5e5d3",
          "53f7d3ec-a65f-4b05-8c82-74f44a7bdc44",
          "60f095d7-1816-4f14-88ec-04412ebde43b",
          "60f095d7-1816-4f14-88ec-04412ebde43b",
          "bec84d69-68f0-456c-a7bd-9f1e94d55a22"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Gendry V. Rineity, the Enigmatic",
      "expansion": 341,
      "power_level": 0,
      "chains": 0,
      "wins": 0,
      "losses": 0,
      "id": "48761c52-1bf0-4437-ba12-f0544237da4e",
      "is_my_deck": false,
      "notes": [],
      "is_my_favorite": false,
      "is_on_my_watchlist": false,
      "casual_wins": 0,
      "casual_losses": 0,
      "_links": {
        "houses": [
          "Dis",
          "Logos",
          "Mars"
        ],
        "cards": [
          "699f06e3-e47b-4910-90b9-c67fac157d6e",
          "10715fd2-031a-47ca-9119-9b7b2ec1d2c0",
          "10715fd2-031a-47ca-9119-9b7b2ec1d2c0",
          "aa73a693-e1e6-4097-8010-ddc820cc6d96",
          "9644c85a-12a7-44ff-a8bb-877dddb46995",
          "750a9323-9c07-4ae7-be5e-79367b4a2a8d",
          "c5ed37f7-0d05-48bc-a595-4f25c0ec1e6d",
          "f97316b0-75a4-45a4-8735-15e72cc1568c",
          "916f271b-9928-437c-bfc4-d60d32af8c7c",
          "3d6a02d0-b5c8-49be-93e4-dfdd5c1200eb",
          "9152cbad-d83f-4ee4-9846-87cc60d185f1",
          "b8343462-b5d7-48b0-9e3b-f020c5e73c55",
          "8c763540-bb69-47aa-be43-4a8ace89864c",
          "f51e8ec0-ab0e-46a8-a5f5-680039d6e664",
          "1838fbaa-a062-4593-acbe-53ecfadfb5cc",
          "1838fbaa-a062-4593-acbe-53ecfadfb5cc",
          "2cb1f58c-5979-4d3a-ae86-9dadc6000288",
          "2cb1f58c-5979-4d3a-ae86-9dadc6000288",
          "2cb1f58c-5979-4d3a-ae86-9dadc6000288",
          "448c1335-d45b-473e-b222-d71f31ba0292",
          "3c5c1881-486c-4911-a3ce-497ef258e8ba",
          "2ec5cbf6-3c41-41ef-9cb7-33a0601fd607",
          "2ec5cbf6-3c41-41ef-9cb7-33a0601fd607",
          "c08c91f0-043a-4a8a-8761-6080e9f46183",
          "16168a85-bbfa-4e54-8c84-5ea02e2a7da1",
          "cc44ca9a-6994-4897-9308-ff332cc8de57",
          "19b74b4e-bec8-4fbb-bd35-cb635f500249",
          "0cc7c1ea-5196-40ff-b408-f31997c8ab4d",
          "179f877a-9b59-46d6-a43e-15b4524af3c6",
          "0e5e8a55-ab05-44be-8637-8362974dad8b",
          "aabeebf7-1da5-4149-afab-e7e221b47d93",
          "a8a3578c-7a61-4e15-90ac-483daf2aff16",
          "1a84631d-7fcb-4c9a-a50c-9539dcb84928",
          "211c5213-7838-4292-b9c4-fb3a663898ee",
          "ac8fb9f6-ee8e-4434-85e8-d084a66c50db",
          "ff104cf4-f99d-4021-a570-dd949e559e97"
        ]
      }
    },


#...
#... there are 25 decks per page. I can only get that many per API call
#...

  "_linked": {     #here are the actual houses per deck and the actual cards
    "houses": [
      {
        "id": "Brobnar",
        "name": "Brobnar",
        "image": "https://cdn.keyforgegame.com/media/houses/Brobnar_RTivg44.png"
      },
      #...more data was in here but there is URL limit
      {
        "id": "Mars",
        "name": "Mars",
        "image": "https://cdn.keyforgegame.com/media/houses/Mars_CmAUCXI.png"
      }
    ],
    "cards": [
      {
        "id": "469dd68d-cdd6-40e0-8fc9-a167c45a9aea",
        "card_title": "Grasping Vines",
        "house": "Untamed",
        "card_type": "Action",
        "front_image": "https://cdn.keyforgegame.com/media/card_front/en/341_324_VH9R4P26824V_en.png",
        "card_text": "Play: Return up to 3 artifacts to their owners’ hands.",
        "traits": null,
        "amber": 1,
        "power": 0,
        "armor": 0,
        "rarity": "Uncommon",
        "flavor_text": null,
        "card_number": 324,
        "expansion": 341,
        "is_maverick": false
      },
      {
        "id": "1a84631d-7fcb-4c9a-a50c-9539dcb84928",
        "card_title": "Yxilo Bolter",
        "house": "Mars",
        "card_type": "Creature",
        "front_image": "https://cdn.keyforgegame.com/media/card_front/en/341_204_H9HQ5F59FJQX_en.png",
        "card_text": "Fight/Reap: Deal 2<D> to a creature. If this damage destroys that creature, purge it.",
        "traits": "Martian • Soldier",
        "amber": 0,
        "power": 3,
        "armor": 0,
        "rarity": "Common",
        "flavor_text": null,
        "card_number": 204,
        "expansion": 341,
        "is_maverick": false
      },   #the data goes on for quite a bit

import json
import requests
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'

class Keyforge():
#    def __init__(self):

    def download(self,pagestart,pagestop):
        #Downloads batches of 25 decks per page. pagestart=1,pagestop=5 will download the first 100 decks in the master vault
        for i in range(pagestart,pagestop):
            response = requests.get("https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/?page="+str(i)+"&links=cards&page_size=25")
            raw_data = json.loads(response.text)
            someitem = raw_data.items()
            columns = list(someitem)
            print (columns)

            with open("keyforge_scraped"+str(i)+".json","w") as data_file:
                json.dump(raw_data,data_file,indent=2)
                print ("Generating batch number %d." % i)
        conn = sqlite3.connect('keyforge.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE "keyforge" ( `deck number` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, `deck name` TEXT, `cardID0` INTEGER, `cardID1` INTEGER, `cardID2` INTEGER, `cardID3` INTEGER, `cardID4` INTEGER, `cardID5` INTEGER, `cardID6` INTEGER, `cardID7` INTEGER, `cardID8` INTEGER, `cardID9` INTEGER, `cardID10` INTEGER, `cardID11` INTEGER, `cardID12` INTEGER, `cardID13` INTEGER, `cardID14` INTEGER, `cardID15` INTEGER, `cardID16` INTEGER, `cardID17` INTEGER, `cardID18` INTEGER, `cardID19` INTEGER, `cardID20` INTEGER, `cardID21` INTEGER, `cardID22` INTEGER, `cardID23` INTEGER, `cardID24` INTEGER, `cardID25` INTEGER, `cardID26` INTEGER, `cardID27` INTEGER, `cardID28` INTEGER, `cardID29` INTEGER, `cardID30` INTEGER, `cardID31` INTEGER, `cardID32` INTEGER, `cardID33` INTEGER, `cardID34` INTEGER, `cardID35` INTEGER, `Wins` INTEGER, `Losses` INTEGER, `Casual wins` INTEGER, `Casual losses` INTEGER )")
        for i in raw_data:
            c.execute("insert into keyforge values (columns[1],?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",columns)
            conn.commit()

        conn.close()
        return raw_data

"""    def updateDB(raw_data):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('keyforge.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS keyforge (id varchar(3), raw_data json)")
        for i in raw_data:
            c.execute("insert into keyforge values (?,?)",[i['id'], json.dumps(raw_data)])
            conn.commit()

        conn.close()
"""


start = int(input("Enter start page: "))
stop = int(input("Enter stop page: "))
a = Keyforge()
raw_data = a.download(start,stop)
#a.updateDB(raw_data)
```

You can see the mess I have created in my code by trying many different things. I am successful in downloading the JSON objects from the website and archiving them to my disk, but I am having no such luck with the sqlite database.

I have created manually using the GUI, the table I want, but I don't know how to populate such table from the JSON data.

Ultimately, what I want is to run my keyforge.py code, select from which page to which page (each page contains 25 decks worth of data) I want to download and process (archive in disk and store in database) and for this database to be updated and increased over time. Obviously, I would also process the data to feed it to my learning algorithm.

Can you guys give me a hand, please? I am stuck in the hole. Please, help me get out of the hole :)

Comment: Just a nitpick, but what you're trying to do is not "parsing".  This is a question about data structures.  It's certainly *possible* to convert some nested JSON-like data structure into a relational database table structure, but this is not always trivial, especially if it's a subject you're new to.  Why do you need to use sqlite3 at all?  Wouldn't be easier for you to use some kind of nosql database?

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 because it was the only thing I found online. I am completely open to use any other database that lets me make queries (I imagine all databases allow this?). Is there any advantage if I chooose nosql? And many thanks for responding!

Comment: There are numerous [document-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database#Implementations) databases, many of which support storage and query of JSON documents natively--no need to transform them into a different datastructure.  [MongoDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) is one of the most popular, and one you will find many resources on, including a decent Python library.  However, there are many others.  You will probably find this much easier if you're not already familiar with design and implementation of relational databases.

Comment: A JSON-formatted datum is a *document*, and the purpose of a documented-oriented database is to store whole documents (e.g. as retrieved from some other source, such as the API you're querying).  A documented-oriented database is designed to store some kinds of semi-structured documents such as JSON and query them in an efficient manner.

Comment: @Iguananaut That is very valuable information! I am such a newbie on these things. I have spent the day learning more about it. There is some material that does exactly what I want, but it costs money, so I think I will keep trying to do it by myself for free. I can feel myself getting closer to the answer, though I think I need to learn much more about databases in general first. Thank you for your generous advice.

Comment: There are plenty of FOSS nosql, document-oriented DBs. For a small project you shouldn't ever need to pay money, not for MongoDB or most anything else. Many of these projects fund themselves with dual-licensing, with free licenses for non-commercial or small scale use. There are even many services that offer free cloud-based hosting for databases, though you can also use them locally.